# Calculation of entropy of an Image using JAVA

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, encryption

I'm working on an Image Encryption program as a part of my academic project in Java.The output of the project would be an encrypted image.Now I need to calculate the entropy of original image and encrypted image for analysis based on this formula
[image: Image Entropy Description]

[image: Sample Data]

How can I find find the entropy of an image according to this equation using Java

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: sorry updated question

Comment: You want someone to write entire code for you?

Comment: Understand the logic first. `p_i` is the probability of the occurrence of the symbol `i`. `i` goes from `1` to `n`. In a grayscale image, `i` will take values from 0-255. Therefore, you just have to count the total number of times `i` occurs divided by total no. of pixels in the image. That becomes your `p_i`. Do this for all values of `i` and calculate using equation (4). This shouldn't be difficult at all.

Comment: So should I convert to gray scale first ?

Comment: @Parag Thank you for the reply so should I convert the jpeg to a greyscale image first ?

Comment: Yes. Convert to grayscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I developed , the entropy value calculated using this is consistent with the entropy() in Matlab thus I'm assuming it to be right please tell me otherwise

```
      public static double getShannonEntropy_Image(BufferedImage actualImage){
 List<String> values= new ArrayList<String>();
             int n = 0;
             Map<Integer, Integer> occ = new HashMap<>();
             for(int i=0;i<actualImage.getHeight();i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<actualImage.getWidth();j++){
                   int pixel = actualImage.getRGB(j, i);
                   int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
                   int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                   int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                   int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
 //0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B greyscale conversion
//System.out.println("i="+i+" j="+j+" argb: " + alpha + ", " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
                   int d= (int)Math.round(0.2989 * red + 0.5870 * green + 0.1140 * blue);
                  if(!values.contains(String.valueOf(d)))
                      values.add(String.valueOf(d));
                  if (occ.containsKey(d)) {
                      occ.put(d, occ.get(d) + 1);
                  } else {
                      occ.put(d, 1);
                  }
                  ++n;
           }
        }
        double e = 0.0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : occ.entrySet()) {
             int cx = entry.getKey();
             double p = (double) entry.getValue() / n;
             e += p * log2(p);
        }
 return -e;
}
```